# Why can't I get the "Curious" badge?

Tags: discussion, questions, badges

[image: Curious badge requirements]

As you can see in the picture above, I have already completed the "Curious" badge's tasks which is *Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record* I already get 5 well-received question on 5 separate days but I still didn't get the badge, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see where the popup's wording can be a little confusing, as it kinda looks like it's saying

> *5/5
>
>   You no longer need to earn the positive record*.

For future reference, when a textual requirement like that is met, the little <kbd>X</kbd> icon turns into a tick like so:

[image: Socratic Badge requirements]

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a positive question record. If you have downvoted questions, deleted questions, etc - these all count against the positive question record.
[This meta.SE post lays it out in full.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges).

According to that post, the metrics "triple counts a question that is downvoted, closed, and deleted. If you ask one that hits that trifecta, you'll need to ask three better questions to dig yourself out."